# Is there a way to invalidate a Android signing key?

Tags: android, android-signing

Now, that there is the new feature of upload keys, developers are able to invalidate keys, when they were exposed somehow.

But what if someone potentially got their hands on your signing key, before you were migrating to upload keys. Are they able to impersonate you and upload an app in your name? Or is the signing key automatically invalidated as you migrate to using upload keys?

If not, is there any other way to invalidate the old signing key?

Comment: AFAIK for uploading an update for one of your apps you require the signing key and your Google credentials. Only for apps that are installed via side-loading you only need the signing key.

Comment: But only because i have a two factor authentication i should not be careless with one of the factors. Both of the should be secure. So not only should i secure the credentials, but also the signing key. That is the reason why i would like to invalidate the old signing key after acquiring the upload key

Comment: I have never heard of a possibility to revoke or invalidate an existing app signing key. The only chance I see is to migrate your apps to a new key. But if I understand it correctly this requires the APK signature scheme v3 and therefore Android 9.